# Google Sheet API Allow Access to external parties

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

Google DOC API V1.

I am trying to add a picture in Google Sheet.

to do so I reference a third party source in the cell:
[image]

However recently end user get the warning message above.

Is there an API to comply and allow External party?

Is there a better way to load pictures in a cell?

Comment: This seems to be caused by recent changes which still has no work around. Similar issue posted recently: [**NEW** IMAGE() URL Fetch Error](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/ihna0293kSY). You may try raising your concern to [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)